# Is there a gui for snap? How do you check for updates and upgrades?

Tags: snap, gui

Is there a GUI frontend for the snap command? I will never remember all those options and don't like to have a tattered printout of the help for reference.

Meanwhile, for immediate problems, what command do I type for checking for updates and upgrades?

Answer (score 2):

There is no GUI. It's not deliberate, but it's also not viewed as neccesary.

Snapd checks for new versions four times each day, and automatically downloads them. The completely-automatic method is a key feature of snaps. If you want snapd to check *now*, run `sudo snap refresh`

- See https://snapcraft.io/docs/keeping-snaps-up-to-date

While it is possible for you to specify a version of snap to run, it's deliberately not a front-and-center feature for users. Developers generally want everybody to run the same version; it's much easier to support that. If you really want to run a previous version, run `sudo snap revert package_name --revision XXXX`

- Note that it's *revision* number, not *version* number. Run `snap list` to see the current revision (and version) numbers for each of your snaps. Snapd is designed to hold at least one older revision (often two older). Revision numbers increment by 1, so it's easy to determine what older revisions you can try.
- See https://snapcraft.io/docs/getting-started

Comment: But for updating, upgrading and installing snap files `gnome-software-plugin-snap` can be installed to let `gnome-software` act as some kind of GUI to manage your snap apps a little?! There is also a plugin for managing your flatpak apps.

Comment: So Plasma Discover is not a GUI for Snap and FlatPak, right?

Comment: If either `gnome-software-plugin-snap` or Plasma Discover offer what the OP is asking, please write an answer so showing. I am unfamiliar with both, and --if there is a GUI alternative-- will happily amend this answer to be accurate.

Comment: The gui is 'snap-store'. It does not check for updates afaik, but it allows adding and remove snaps. 

https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-store-app

Comment: The OP's comment "*I will never remember all those options*" suggests that they want a GUI to handle more than basic installing/removal. However, you might be right -- the question is vague.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with Linux, and as of Jul 2 - 2023, there is GUI for non-Ubuntu Linux distributions (at least the ones that I have installed), but for the latest LTS and for the latest regular releases of Ubuntu itself there is no separate GUI available, as all the software (snap or Debian) are supposed to be displayed together in the Ubuntu Software app.

Best,
Abba